# How to check a select box option in Ionic framework from the controller using Angular 8+?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ion-select

I have a FormGroup as follow :

```
public form = this.fb.group({
        name: ['', [Validators.minLength(3), Validators.required]],
        category: ['', [Validators.required]],
        start_date: ['', [Validators.required]],
        end_date: ['', [Validators.required]],
        front_image: ['', [Validators.required]],
        description: ['']
    }, {validators: [verifyDates]})
```

And my select field in the html formGroup as follow :

```
 <ion-item>
  <ion-label>{{'selectCat' | translate}}</ion-label>
  <ion-select placeholder="{{'selectCatPlaceholder' | translate}}" formControlName="category" required>
    <ion-select-option  *ngFor="let cat of catService.categories" [value]="cat">{{cat.get('name_' + trans.currentLang)}}</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Is there a way to check the correct option from the controller ?

I'm updating the form control on init in this mannear

```
this.form.get('category').setValue(cat[0])
```

It updates the form value correctly but does not check the box on the frontend. I use form builder and not ngModels and I used to use ngModels with formControl before but not it says we can't anymore and I can't find a way to do it. Can someone help ?

Comment: "but does not check the box on the frontend" What does that mean?

Comment: The input does not update with the selection like it should by setting the value. Is there a way to use ngModel with form builder?

Comment: Are you using a `<form>` tag and binding to your form? `<form [formGroup]="form">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
value ="{{cat}}"
```